# Computer logs out during screen sharing in Kubuntu 22.04 and later versions

Tags: apt, crash, zoom-meeting

The computer crashes and logs out within 5-10 minutes after screen sharing in Zoom and Chromium (zoom web client).

During the crash, I get logged out, and I have to login again (all running applications get killed). The error keeps happening again and again, in almost every Zoom meeting.

I am using Kubuntu 22.04 (same issue also present in Kubuntu 23.04, Xubuntu 22.04 and Mint 21. Perhaps 22.04 and all later versions are affected).

I have 12 GB of RAM. I kept checking system monitor, and found that memory usage remained under 4 GB. So, the computer did not run out of memory.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/15L1Ektz) is the stack trace, which repeatedly says

```
warning: Can't open file anon_inode:i915.gem which was expanded to anon_inode:i915.gem during file-backed mapping note processing
```

Here is a log file from the KDE crash handler.

```
Application: kded5 (kded5), signal: Aborted

[KCrash Handler]
#4  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140189578186304) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#5  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=140189578186304) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
#6  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=140189578186304, signo=signo@entry=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#7  0x00007f806ec42476 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#8  0x00007f806ec287f3 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#9  0x00007f806f490ba3 in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007f806bb1be45 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WaylandClient.so.5
#11 0x00007f806bb2c11a in QtWaylandClient::QWaylandDisplay::flushRequests() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WaylandClient.so.5
#12 0x00007f806f6f17c8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007f806f6f4cb3 in QSocketNotifier::activated(QSocketDescriptor, QSocketNotifier::Type, QSocketNotifier::QPrivateSignal) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007f806f6f54e3 in QSocketNotifier::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007f807056c713 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#16 0x00007f806f6b9e3a in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#17 0x00007f806f713cc5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0x00007f806e3c7d3b in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007f806e41d258 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007f806e3c53e3 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007f806f7130b8 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0x00007f806f6b875b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007f806f6c0cf4 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#24 0x00005563b9674e52 in ?? ()
#25 0x00007f806ec29d90 in __libc_start_call_main (main=main@entry=0x5563b96744e0, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7ffd4573e578) at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#26 0x00007f806ec29e40 in __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x5563b96744e0, argc=1, argv=0x7ffd4573e578, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffd4573e568) at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#27 0x00005563b9675525 in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 21063) detached]
```

I got  `zoom[2316]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f29403b6cd0 sp 00007ffdf0113438 error 4 in libQt5Gui.so.5[7f2940200000+714000]` in `dmesg` of Xubuntu 22.04.

Does anyone know any workaround?

This issue is absent in Kubuntu 18.04, Kubuntu 20.04 and Mint 20.3 (based on Ubuntu 20.04).

My laptop model number is HP 250 G5. It has an Intel i3-6006U CPU with Intel® HD Graphics 520 (no dedicated graphics).

My other computer running Kubuntu 22.04 is unaffected, but the HP 250 G5 laptop experiences the same sort of crash in multiple distros based on Ubuntu 22.04 and later.

Comment: @user68186 I have updated the question, The issue seems to be absent in multiple Ubuntu 20.04 based distros. Also, my other computer running Kubuntu 22.04 is unaffected.

Comment: Your edits made me think it may be a hardware issue. I will try to replicate it on my computers

Comment: This issue was absent in the laptop until I started using 22.04 (and later versions). I used 18.04 and 20.04 based operating systems on the same laptop for years, and the issue never occurred. To replicate the issue, you may have to share screen for 5-10 minutes, and keep closing/opening apps. It does not seem to be triggered by any particular app.

Comment: I had a zoom meeting with myself connecting an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop running the Zoom desktop client to a PopOS 22.04 laptop running Zoom in Chrome browser. I shared open GEdit window from both (in turn), but didn't get any crashes.

Comment: It only crashes in one of my four computers (also, it takes 5-10 minutes of regular usage before it crashes). It may be affecting very few computers, and your computers may be unaffected.

Comment: To me this confirms the problem is hardware specific,and thus difficult to replicate. Best of luck.

Comment: @user68186 I added the link to stack trace, which is filled with `warning: Can't open file anon_inode:i915.gem which was expanded to anon_inode:i915.gem during file-backed mapping note processing`.

Comment: I have no idea what that warning means.